# Svelte and D3 brush

Tags: d3.js, brush, svelte

I'm struggling to understand how to use Svelte with something like D3's [brush project](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush). Svelte operates using a declarative approach. In the [area chart example](https://svelte.dev/examples#area-chart) the SVG for lines is written out in the template HTML. To do this with D3 you would use Javascript function calls to select an element and call another function to modify the DOM. In the aforementioned chart example the D3 scaled library is only used to generate the axis array but the HTML itself is managed by Svelte. It makes sense Svelte works this way - building things up with function calls would be a lot less clean, but I can't figure out how to do this with the brush. How can I declaratively build up the brush HTML inside of my Svelte template, and how would this affect things like brush events? Would it rather be best to just use the brush functions inside of say onMount and sort-of tie change events to local Svelte variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this myself https://svelte.dev/repl/00f726facd434b978c737af2698e0dbc?version=3.12.1

As Mikkel said above, the way Svelte is designed doesn't play well naturally with something like D3. As I see it you have two options: try to wire D3 events into Svelte's reactive variables, or try to implement the functionality yourself.

I opted for the second version. I took the HTML and CSS that D3 Brush created, adding a mouse handler to the carets, and tied all the variables together reactively. (The last part I did very messily. Would appreciate any feedback on doing this cleaner from other Svelte users).

Answer (score 3):

The same problem exists in React, because both React and D3 want to be in charge of the DOM. In React you simply call the a function that instructs D3 to do it's work in the ComponentDidMount method (or a useEffect if using hooks.

Svelte expects to be in charge of the situation, you declare how the UI is constructed, and define the operations, leaving it to do the work. It won't be able to track what D3 does, so I suspect you need to just let D3 be in charge of that part, and not worry about it being a little bit hacky.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I like the way you say "want to be in charge of the DOM". That's a good way to conceptualise it.

Comment: I'm busy working up the D3 brush functionality manually. Svelte is clean enough that I think it will be a good solution but it makes me worry about down the line how other libraries can cooperate (do they all need to be Svelte extensions to play nice?)

Comment: I'd be interested to see how you do it, if you don't mind sharing your code when it's ready?

Comment: Sure no problem, I’ll post the code here. Should be a day or so.

Comment: Hey @Mikkel I managed to get it working (see my own answer). It's messy, but it works!

Answer (score 2):

It also took me a bit to wrap my head around this. But in the end it's actually not that complicated. They key step is to decide which library takes care of which responsibility.

D3 simply overlaps with Svelte since it also renders things on the screen. But if you think about it, you don't really need a renderer if you already have Svelte. Once you have a renderer, the complicated part about charts is really the positioning. And this is where D3 *really* shines. If you "cherry pick" the best from both worlds you actually end up with a great dev experience. 
But, alas, you can also leave the rendering to D3. But then you need to keep Svelte out of the picture as much as possible.

**Essentially you have two options that both work well:**

1. Svelte renders only the container DOM and then hands over to D3 to both calculate & render. You interface between both worlds only during onMount and onDestroy
2. Svelte renders the whole DOM, D3 provides the chart positions.

**As for the brush functionality:**

I found it to work best to create a ChartContainer (which is essentially just an SVG) with slots and then drop a Brush component inside.

```
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

  export let minX;
  export let maxX;

  export let dX = 0;

  export let height;

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

  let startX,
      endX,
      mouseDown = false,
      brushArea;

  function onMouseDown(event) {
    if (mouseDown) return;

    mouseDown = true;

    brushArea.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    brushArea.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);

    brushArea.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    brushArea.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);

    brushArea.style.cursor = "ew-resize";

    startX = Math.max(event.offsetX - dX, minX);
    endX = null;
  }

  function onMouseMove(event) {
    endX = Math.min(event.offsetX - dX, maxX);
  }

  function onMouseUp(event) {
    mouseDown = false;

    if (!endX) startX = null;

    brushArea.style.cursor = null;

    brushArea.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
    brushArea.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);

    const active = !!startX;

    dispatch("brush", {active, startX, endX, clear});
  }

  function clear() {
    startX = null;
    endX = null;
  }

</script>

<rect class="ui--chart__brush_area"
      bind:this={brushArea}
      x={minX}
      y="0"
      height={height}
      width={maxX-minX}
      on:mousedown={onMouseDown}
/>

{#if endX != null}
  <rect class="ui--chart__brush"
        x={startX < endX ? startX : endX}
        y="0"
        height={height}
        width={startX < endX ? endX-startX : startX-endX}
  />
{/if}
```

The dX prop is used to consider a left margin. Might or might not be required in your use case (depending on how you setup your chart). The key thing is to be able to use offsetX from the mouse event so that you know how far off from the SVG borders your mouse events have fired.

Then, you just

- listen for the brush events
- extract the coordinates
- convert them to values -by using yourScale.invert(coordinate)
- use these values, e.g. to update your chart

Like so:

```js
 function onBrush(event) {
    const {active, startX, endX, clear} = event.detail;
    if (active) {
      const startDate = scaleX.invert(startX);
      const endDate = scaleX.invert(endX);

      dispatch("brush", {active, startX, endX, startDate, endDate, clear});
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps anyone else struggling with this. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a single answer to your question, but I think the best option is to render the "most relevant data" using svelte's html, leaving the interactive elements (like brush) to run only on client side.

You should known that svelte converts your html to js generators internally, so calling the d3 functions is actually pretty similar to what svelte does client side. The only real advantage of using the svelte's html instead of d3 functions calls is SSR, and that's the reason it's reasonable to leave the brush to be client side only (since it needs js to be interactive anyway).

Svelte is kind of a "reactive vanilla", so you can use low-level libraries almost directly. Sometimes you need to do some tricks to access DOM elements directly (like d3 usually does), for that I recommend using the `bind:this` directive. Example:

```html
<script>
  import { brushX, select } from 'd3';

  //...

  let brushElement;

  $: brush = brushX()
      .extent([[padding.left, padding.top], [width - padding.right, height - padding.bottom]])
      .on('end', onZoom)
  
  $: if (brushElement) {
    select(brushElement)
      .call(brush)
  }
</script>

<svg>
  ...
  <g bind:this={brushElement} width={...} height={...} />
  ...
</svg>
```

One thing to consider when using DOM's API is SSR (sapper), thus any call of d3's `select` should be done only in the browser. The if case in the code above takes care of that, because the `bind:this` directive will only set `brushElement` when running client side.